# Parse enum from json

Tags: json, flutter, parsing, enums

I have an `enum`

```
enum Mode { standard, relative, fixed }

extension ModeMap on Mode {
  static const valueMap = {
    Mode.standard: "standard",
    Mode.relative: "relative",
    Mode.fixed: "fixed",
  };
  String? get value => valueMap[this];
}
```

And a model using this enum with a method `fromJson`:

```
class Settings {
  Mode mode;
  String name;

  Settings({
    required this.mode,
    required this.name,
  });

  Settings.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : mode = Mode[json['Mode'].toString()] as Mode,
        name = json['Name'],


  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['Mode'] = mode.value;
    data['Name'] = name;
    return data;
  }
}
```

However, it seems that I can't transform the values from json to my enum this way. What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the reverse of what you did with the `value` getter. The following code makes a `fromString` method to get a `Mode` from a `String` by reversing your `valueMap`. You then can use it with `ModeMap.fromString(json['Mode'])` in your factory constructor.

```dart
enum Mode { standard, relative, fixed }

extension ModeMap on Mode {
  static const valueMap = {
    Mode.standard: "standard",
    Mode.relative: "relative",
    Mode.fixed: "fixed",
  };
  String? get value => valueMap[this];
  
  static Mode fromString(String input) {
    final reverseValueMap = valueMap.map<String, Mode>((key, value) => MapEntry(value, key));
    
    Mode? output = reverseValueMap[input];
    if(output == null) {
      throw 'Invalid String Input';
    }
    
    return output;
  }
}

class Settings {
  Mode mode;
  String name;

  Settings({
    required this.mode,
    required this.name,
  });

  Settings.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : mode = ModeMap.fromString(json['Mode']),
        name = json['Name'];


  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['Mode'] = mode.value;
    data['Name'] = name;
    return data;
  }
}
```